# Geometry, showing if F is diffeomorphism then tangent map is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry

[image]

Show that if f is a diffeomorphism, then Tp1(f) is invertible for all P1 member of S1.

I've already proved its a linear map, I just need to show that the kernel is 0. How does one go about doing so?

Comment: Try to use the chain rule

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon that the easiest way to show something is invertible is to just write down its inverse, and prove that it really is the inverse.

I assert that is one of those cases.

Comment: Still don't understand!